# Fixing"FeatureCollection (Error) Image.reduceToVectors: First band ('rh100') of image must be integral"

Tags: google-earth-engine, vector, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to extract the datapoints from GEDI collection and choose the points which lower than 60 in Google Earth Engine by using **ReducetoVector**. I'm getting this error:

> FeatureCollection (Error) Image.reduceToVectors: First band ('rh100')
> of image must be integral

and I have no idea how to fix it. My code:

```
var  aoi = 
/* color: #00ff00 */
/* displayProperties: [
  {
    "type": "rectangle"
  }
] */
ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[10.752981103928594, 0.7627966289396413],
      [10.752981103928594, -0.7615114430026542],
      [13.104055322678594, -0.7615114430026542],
      [13.104055322678594, 0.7627966289396413]]], null, false);

// GEDI pre-processing

var gedi = ee.ImageCollection('LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_A_002_MONTHLY')
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .map(function (image) {
    return image
      .updateMask(image.select('sensitivity').gt(0.98)) //update sensitivity > 98%
      .updateMask(image.select('quality_flag').eq(1))
      .updateMask(image.select('degrade_flag').eq(0))
      .select('rh100');
  })

var projection = gedi.first().projection().aside(print);
var scale = projection.nominalScale().aside(print);
var mosaic = gedi.mosaic().setDefaultProjection({crs:projection, scale:scale});
var mosaicMask = mosaic.lt(60)
var mosaic = mosaic.updateMask(mosaicMask)
print(mosaic)   


var referenceData = mosaic
    .reduceToVectors({
      geometry: aoi,
      geometryType: 'polygon',
      scale : scale,
      maxPixels : 100e9,
      tileScale:16,
      crs: projection,

          })
print(referenceData)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4e46ac32cf1d4b2097284c69733dd388

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need '.toInt' method in gedi variable. As **referenceData** feature collection is very huge (it has 463611 features), you cannot use print statement. It is necessary to export directly to Drive as in following code snippet.

```
var gedi = ee.ImageCollection('LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_A_002_MONTHLY')
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .map(function (image) {
    return image
      .updateMask(image.select('sensitivity').gt(0.98)) //update sensitivity > 98%
      .updateMask(image.select('quality_flag').eq(1))
      .updateMask(image.select('degrade_flag').eq(0))
      .select('rh100')
      .toInt();
  });
.
.
.

//print("referenceData", referenceData);

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: referenceData,
  folder: 'GEE_Folder',
  description:'referenceData',
  fileFormat: 'SHP'
});
```

After running [complete code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f94e6c7799d3d0ab8e099f18fdee261e) in GEE code editor, I got following shapefile, visualized with QGIS 3, after running task in corresponding Tab. It can be corroborated that this polygon layer (situated in Gabon) has 463611 features.

[image]

Comment: Thank you in advance. It helps me a lot.

Comment: How much time does this take to run in the code editor ?

Comment: For me, seven minutes.